# I have two values in an array when i execute the stored Procedure in php But iam returned wih one array value

Tags: php

```
$result = $mysql->callSP('STOREDPE1',$in);
    $arr_tmp=array();
    foreach ($result['record'] as $rows) {
        echo "one value";
        if(!empty($rows)){
            echo "Two Value";
            $arr_tmp[$rows['field1']] = $rows['field2'];
        }
    }

    return $arr_tmp;
```

When I say `var_dump($result)` it has two values in array. But when I Execute `arr_tmp` it is returned with one value.

out put of ``var_dump($result)`

```
 ["param"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["whcode"]=>
    string(5) "001"
    ["mode"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["stock_type"]=>
    string(4) "AAA"
    ["process_name"]=>
    string(7) "AAAA"
  }
  ["record"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["Field1"]=>
      string(5) "value1"
      ["Field2"]=>
      string(1) "CCC"
      ["Field3"]=>
      string(4) "BCC"
    }
    [1]=>
     [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["Field1"]=>
      string(5) "value1"
      ["Field2"]=>
      string(1) "CCC"
      ["Field3"]=>
      string(4) "BCC"
    }
  }
}
```

output of `var_dump (arr_tmp)`

```
[1]=>
     [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["Field1"]=>
      string(5) "value1"
      ["Field2"]=>
      string(1) "CCC"
      ["Field3"]=>
      string(4) "BCC"
    }

Both the array values seems  to be same
```

I have the values overwriting in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very hard to understand and read with the bad formatting, please take care to post it with proper formatting.

I think the answer is this:

```
$result = $mysql->callSP('STOREDPE1',$in); 
$arr_tmp=array();
foreach ($result['record'] as $rows) { 
    echo "one value"; 
    if(!empty($rows)){ 
        echo "Two Value"; 
        $arr_tmp[][$rows['field1']] = $rows['field2']; 
    } 
}

var_dump($arr_tmp);
```

That should store both sets of data, you just needed to make it a multi-dimensional array. That is, if that is your question and I did not mis-read it through that garbled text above.

**Update**

This option is not recommended better to learn how to use arrays, simply posted for an example of usage:

```
$result = $mysql->callSP('STOREDPE1',$in); 
$arr_tmp=array();
$i=0;
foreach ($result['record'] as $rows) { 
    echo "one value"; 
    if(!empty($rows)){ 
        echo "Two Value"; 
        $arr_tmp[][$rows['field1'] . "_$i"] = $rows['field2']; 
    }
    $i++; 
}

var_dump($arr_tmp);
```

Comment: I dont want to have double dimensional array .It is very tough to assign values and need to change a lot of thing can we use the same above code and assign the same values without double dimensional

Comment: The only way would be to make the field names unique, which they currently are not. You can append a 1 to the field names (example given) but it is much better to learn how to work with arrays.